# Multivariate gaussian bivariate gaussian proof

Tags: normal-distribution, multivariate-analysis, covariance-matrix, bivariate, determinant

I'm having trouble seeing how the multivariate gaussian formula evaluates to the bivariate gaussian. See multivariate PDF, source: http://cs229.stanford.edu/section/gaussians.pdf

[![multivariate][1]][1]

And bivariate gaussian formula, source: http://clements.ece.gatech.edu/4260.sp17/bivariate_notes.pdf

[![Bivariate][2]][2]

My best guess is that I might have an error on either the determinant or matrix inverse. If the below is true:

```py
cov = [[(s1)^2, p      ],
       [p,      (s2)^2 ]] # where s1 represents standard deviation of x1

det([[a b],
     [c d]]) = ad - bc

inv([[a b],
     [c d]]) = [[d/(det), -b/(det)],
                [-c/(det), a/(det)]]
```

Then the following:

```py
det(cov) = (s1)^2 * (s2)^2 - p^2

inv(cov) = [[(s2)^2/(det), -p/(det)],
            [-p/(det),     (s1)^2/(det)]]
```

Using the above when plugging info into the multivariate gaussian, I was not able to simplify the PDF into the bivariate gaussian. Again, I suspect that I made an error in the determinant, the inverse, or perhaps there is a relationship between s1, s2, and p that I don't understand.

Any thoughts, advice, etc is greatly appreciated!

Edit: In response to gunes' answer, I've updated my calculation of what the matrix inverse should be:

```py
inv(cov) = (1/(1-p^2))* [[1/(s1)^2, -p/(s1*s2)],
                         [-p/(s1*s2), 1/(s2)^2]]
```

Can this be confirmed as accurate
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsRE8.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DATnW.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The covariance matrix is $$\Sigma=\begin{bmatrix}\sigma_1^2&\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2\\\rho\sigma_1\sigma_2&\sigma_2^2\end{bmatrix}$$

But, in your formula the off diagonals are $\rho$.

Comment: Ah, it looks like this is where I was confused. I had thought `p` was the covariance between (s1,s2) but maybe I'm wrong. Is it the Pearson correlation coefficient..?

Comment: Yes, it's the typical letter used to denote Pearson correlation coef.